# How to enable Cheat mode in NEI?(For Mac)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've searched for anything to help with changing the NEI mod from recipe mode into cheat mode, but none worked sadly, I use a Mac and most tutorials and related are for Windows and other stuff that aren't for Mac, so is there any way possible to change this?

Answer (score 1):

Open your inventory with whatever key you use, and click on the button in the bottom left called "options". From there go into inventory settings (or depending on your version, straight click on cheat mode). From there you can see a button called "recipe mode". Click it until it says "cheat mode". Congratulations! You are now in cheat mode.